# Gulp + Angular + Springboot + Gradle + [...]

Tags: java, angularjs, gradle, spring-boot, gulp

I was learning a bit of *Angular + Springboot* and now it's time to learn how to build all that stuff :)

I've found some quite good tools such as *Gulp + Gradle*, but I'm not sure how I configure all that together. On Gulp I'll use some tasks such as sass, minify. I also want to use karma (which I assume I would configure with gulp instead of running it separately). `Gradle` is for building the springboot and Java backend for `REST api`..

How should I configure all that together?
I thought it would be something like configuring `Gradle` to run Gulp first, and then build the java part. Is that right ? What is the best approach?

And besides of that, how to run it in Development time? one thing I liked in Gulp and `Springboot` is that both give the ability to edit + visualize the static content in real time, so it's quite good for building the angular part.. So with that, would I use `gulp` or the `gradle` task `bootRun` (I would have to change configure it differently as I'm using *gulp-browserify*). If I use gulp, I would have to build the java part separately, and it would have to be running in other port so I would have to configure CORS on angular..

Can anyone shed some light ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could get some ideas by checking out the way [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/) handles the integration

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I will check that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use maven-frontend-plugin.
see JHipster. https://jhipster.github.io/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I will check that, (and probably use JHipster :) )

Answer (score 0):

Sorry buddy, I'm noting using gulp or gradles. But I'm using webpack+Angular4 and Maven+Springboot for backend Restful APIs.

What I'm doing is to setting up an proxy for webpack.dev.js:

```html
devServer: {
      stats: 'minimal',
      inline: true,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3200,
      open: true,
      proxy: {
        "*/app-tool/**": {
          target: "http://localhost:8080",
          secure: false, 
        }
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
    }
```

With the above, all the api calls from Angular4 redirect from localhost:3200/apis
to 
localhost:8080/app-tool/apis

Hope to give you another way for solving your problems.